Visiting Every Touristic Point Without Walking on the Same Path Twice
Original Problem

There are $6$ touristic points of interest in a very small pentagonal town, labelled in the diagram by $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ and $O$, and the line segments represent a path between them. Your bus drops you at point $A$ and will pick you up at point $D$. How many ways can you visit all points without walking on the same path twice? Note: you can pass through the same touristic place more than once.


What I Have Tried
I tried to solve the problem using brute force by drawing a tree diagram that starts from $A$ and ends at $D$, but I eventually gave up because it was taking too long. Here is a picture of a part of the tree:

I also tried searching the question up, but there were no relevant problems. I did although find something that might be useful: Hamiltonian paths, but I don't know a lot about graph theory and how to use Hamiltonian paths, so I've come to a dead end.
My Question
Is there a faster and cleaner way to solve this problem? If so, how?
Thanks in advance.
Edit
After looking at the definition of Hamiltonian paths again, I noticed that Hamiltonian paths can only visit every vertex exactly once, which isn't the case for this problem, since we can visit every touristic point as many times as we need.

Here is rather clean way to do it:
$E$ is of degree $3$, so either $A$ or $D$ will appear just before it or just after it in the path.
By symmetry, we can suppose that $E$ is visited just after $A$, so the first visited vertices in order are $A$ then $E$. The only possible way to continue is to visit $O$ (otherwise, we close the path without visiting every vertex). Then we have two possible choices, but we quickly see that only one gives a solution, so there is only one possible path visiting $A$ then $E$, and by symmetry, only one visiting $E$ then $D$, so two in total.
Your idea of brute force can also work efficiently if you combine it with a good pruning mechanism. For example, you can avoid visiting $D$ if we have not visited every other vertices. You can discard branches where one vertex not yet visited have only one neighbors not in the already visited vertices, not including the current vertex. By extension, when a vertex has only one neighbor outside visited vertices and the current visited vertex, then the only possible branch is to visit next this vertex.
So in your case, your search tree (with lexicographic DFS) would look like this:
Start of the DFS
A
AB
ABC
ABCO (we do not visit D since we haven't visited all vertices yet)
ABCOE (same, we don't yet visit D)
ABCOED (first path)
ABO 
Now, both C and E are forced move because these have both exactly one non-visited neighbor and O as a neighbor, but we can't visit both of them on next turn, so this will not lead to new paths, and we can backtrack
AE
AEO
AEOB (B is forced move)
AEOBC
AEOBCD (second path)
AO
AOE (E is forced)
We are stuck because there are no vertices so we backtrack.
End of the DFS

